# Wireless mouse with at least 8 supported buttons

Tags: linux, wifi, mouse

I'm trying to find a wireless mouse fully supported under Linux, with at least 8 recognized buttons: left, right, the wheel as scrolling + middle button and I would use the remaining 3 for moving, resizing and closing windows (using mappings in compiz).

I've already tried several mouse, but in all of them many buttons are not recognized or not working (checked with xev). Is there a wireless mouse that satisfies this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for hardware recommendations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verbatim has an [eight button mouse](https://www.verbatim.com/prod/mice/mice-desktop/deluxe-mice--sku-99021/) with explicit Linux support, in grey, purple, red, or blue.